# Is it possible to get URL of the page when sharing the selected text from the Chrome or other web-browser app?

Tags: android

In my app i handle `Intent.ACTION_SEND` intent sent from other apps.

One of such senders can be the `Chrome` app.

I can simply send the URL of the current page or the selected text from the Chrome app to my app via built-in 'Share to ...' functionality inside the Chrome. In both cases in my app I can access the shared text via `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`.

However for the case when selected text is shared additionally to the text itself I would like to receive the URL of the page to which this text belong.
I've blindly tried several other `Intent.EXTRA_xxx` fields but without any luck.

Does anyone know is it possible at all? Is it more-or-less universal or app-specific?
In case if it is not possible to receive this info from the intent, are there any other ways to achieve the similar goal? Maybe somehow ask the chrome-app directly what is/was the current page? Will be glad to any ideas...